# Can I write inside a xml node using Ruby/Builder?

Tags: ruby, xml, watir, builder

There's my code:

```
require 'builder'

def initXML(builder)
    builder.instruct!
    builder.results(:result => 'result'){}
end 
def writeXML(builder,name,hello)    
    builder.test(:name => name){
        builder.hello hello
        }
end 
builder = Builder::XmlMarkup.new(:target=> STDOUT, :indent=>4)
initXML(builder)
writeXML(builder,'name1','hello1')
writeXML(builder,'name2','hello2')
```

Executing that I get this XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<results result="result">
</results>
<test name="name1">
    <hello>hello1</hello>
</test>
<test name="name2">
    <hello>hello2</hello>
</test>
```

But I want the `</results>` end tag at the end of file. There's a way to write inside the `<results>` node? Or move the `</results>` to the end of file? Is better to use Nokogiri? Or is better to generate my XML manually? I'm trying to use that with Watir unit testing, there's something can I use to do that to write my results on a XML file?

(Update)That's the XML I want:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <results result="result">    
    <test name="name1">
        <hello>hello1</hello>
    </test>
    <test name="name2">
        <hello>hello2</hello>
    </test>
    </results>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's writing precisely what you're telling it to.

Pass a block into `initXML` (which would be `init_xml` in idiomatic Ruby, IMO) and execute it. But I wouldn't call it `init_xml`, because what you're actually doing is wrapping XML content.

I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish; this is easily done using normal builder semantics. If you want to return XML nodes from a method consider passing the current node to a method, perhaps. Without knowing precisely what you're trying to do, it's difficult to advise.

Comment: @Marcelo We understand the XML you want, I'm asking what are you trying to accomplish by using the methods. In the example you give there isn't much reason to use them; it's essentially as short using normal builders.

Comment: I want to run my tests on Watir using test/unit, in each test i want to write the result and another things in the XML, calling my methods, but when I put the tag `<results>`, the builder close the tag automatically, I want to write the tag, write the results in tags inside `<results>`, then in the end of the tests close with `</results>`. I`m new on Ruby and I don`t know if I can do this with builder.

Comment: ci_reporter will automatically create xml reports: https://github.com/nicksieger/ci_reporter/